# Highchart change series value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to change series on highchart properties series?
this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxEnH/610/)

its similiar like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NxEnH/8/) but different structure

i want to change many type of series like this

```
series: [{
            name: 'Nominal',
            data: [
                { name: 'Remunerasi', y: 200000, color: 'red'},
                { name: 'Penyesuaian Gaji', y: 1200000, color: 'yellow' }
            ]
        }]


//or this
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    data: [
        { name: 'Promosi', y: 33.38 },
        { name: 'Upgrading', y: 14.77 }, 
        { name: 'GP Dibawah Min', y: 22.91 },
        { name: 'Kontrak Kedua', y: 20}
    ]
}]


//or this

series: [{
        name: 'Sebelum',
        data: [200000, 300000, 400000, 400000],
        color : 'red'
    },{
        name: 'Setelah',
        data: [400000,600000,800000,800000],
        color : 'yellow'
    },{
        name: 'Kenaikan',
        data: [200000, 300000, 400000, 400000],
        color : 'blue'
    }]
```

Im trying to change the value inside those series using a button

Comment: You need to use [point.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.update) and update a specific point with new options - see example http://jsfiddle.net/vcv3jvxv/

Comment: Or, using `setData()`: http://jsfiddle.net/NxEnH/612/

Answer (score -1):

i hope this tuto help you 
setdata:Apply a new set of data to the series and optionally redraw it. The new data array is passed by reference (except in case of updatePoints), and may later be mutated when updating the chart data.